# Checkbox and Textview alignment with white space

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with my XML layout. As you see in the image below, the textview is next to the checkbox (which doesn't include any `android:text` field . How can I remove the space I've underlined with blue?

[image]

Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDisinstalla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/disinstalla"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbAbilitaServizio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/abilita_servizio" >
            </CheckBox>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbSpegniSchermo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/spegni_schermo" >
            </CheckBox>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbLandscape"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/landscape" >
            </CheckBox>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bCalibrazione"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/calibrazione" />
```

Problematic code:

```
            <!-- BELOW THERE IS THE PROBLEMATICCODE -->
            <!-- BELOW THERE IS THE PROBLEMATICCODE -->
            <!-- BELOW THERE IS THE PROBLEMATICCODE -->
            <!-- BELOW THERE IS THE PROBLEMATICCODE -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ripetisfondo"
                android:padding="1dp" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:shadowColor="#000000"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:text="@string/titolo1"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->
```

Rest of the code:

```
            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:padding="1dp" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#555555"
                android:padding="1dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_5"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sbNumeroPassate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMilliseconds"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_1a" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCurrentWaves"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_current" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_2a" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_4a" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:padding="1dp" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#555555"
                android:padding="1dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_6"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sbMillisecTraPassate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMilliseconds"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_1b" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCurrentInterval"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_current" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_2b" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_4b" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:padding="1dp" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#555555"
                android:padding="1dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/impostazioni_7"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <!-- TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO   TITOLO -->

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAccensioni"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/statistica_1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpegnimenti"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/statistica_2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPotenzaUsata"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/statistica_3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBottoneSalvato"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/statistica_4" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bSalva"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/impostazioni_salva" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you paste only the single checkbox and single textview xml code which are in problem

Comment: there are many textview in your layout which to read is a pain

Comment: there are 4 comment that indicate the exact point

Comment: whats wrong with removing unnecessary one

Comment: Now it should be easy to find it... I pased the whole code because you usually ask the whole code to understand the problem

Comment: So the "WAVE HAN" is the label for CheckBox?

Comment: I solved it merging the whole code in the CheckBox one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a seperate TextView to display a String why not use the text property of Checkbox?

```
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/titolo1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```